# tensorflow versioning mis-match in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have no idea, why my python is acting so weirdly. I had tensorflow-2.3, as that doesn't go with cuda-10.1, so I had to go back to tensorflow-2.1. So my commands were :

```
pip uninstall tensorflow tensorflow-gpu
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0 tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0
```

But when I try to use tensorflow in python, it says it's version 2.3.

When I tried to uninstall the second time, it says I have 2.1.0.

**Then why python is showing version 2.3 instead of 2.1?**

Here is a snap :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing to python3.6.
But your “python” command is executing python3.7
Try typing python3.6

PS: Use conda for python environment management.

Comment: ok, thanks, I have used `pip3.6 install blah` and `pip3.7 install blah`.. not it's done..